# Contacts cannot sync

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, calendar, contacts

Contacts on my iPhone, MacBook, and iCloud failed to sync; now I have three different Contacts versions on them! I have tried all methods listed in https://support.apple.com/en-us/102543 as well as searching on internet, including:

1. restart phone/computer
2. phone/computer/icloud in the same Apple ID
3. close and reopen Contacts on icloud, Calendars, and Reminders
4. all iOS/macOS are in the newest version
5. data and time are the same and correct
6. close the app and wait
7. refresh the app
8. iCloud is set as default
9. clear the Chrome cookie, refresh, and log in to iCloud again.

None of them work. This is ridiculous. Can someone offer some suggestions or help? Appreciate.

Comment: Have you signed out of iCloud on both devices, waited a bit, then signed back in?

Comment: do you feel like deleting them on phone and mac, since they are saved on iCloud to repopulate